# Unable to add Ec2 VPC Security group in Non VPC RDS MySQL Security group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I was trying to whitelist an VPC security to a non VPC DB Security group. But the VPC security group is not in the list in the dropdown. So i am not sure, is it possible to whitelist VPC Security into a non VPC Security group?

Comment: Is the DB in the same VPC region?.

Comment: Yes both are in same region.

Comment: Can an instance inside a VPC contact a non-VPC RDS instance directly without looping out to the Internet and back in?  I don't see how that would work, and when connections are from the Internet, you can only allow the traffic by listing the IP address, not the SG, even when you're hairpinning out and back in.

Answer (score 1):

I received response from AWS, you simply cant add a non VPC Security group to VPC security group. you can add only a VPC security group to a VPC Security group. So only option i have is to first migrate RDS MYSQL instance and all instance of Ec2 to VPC. and thn add VPC security group of instances to RDS security group.

Answer (score 0):

Security Groups are VPC specific. Ensure that your VPC Security groups, RDS instance and DB security group belong to the same VPC.

(or)

If your requirement is to have multiple VPCs, then peer your VPCs. Once the VPCs are peered, you will see your VPC security group in the dropdown list.

PS: There is no such thing called **non vpc**. If you don't specify any VPC, AWS will provision your resources in the **default vpc**.

Comment: AWS never put your resource in default VPC by default. By default it will be in Ec2-Classic. (which i mentioning as non-VPC, publicly available)

Comment: Try validating it. Resources like RDS / Security Groups can sit only inside a VPC. If you don't specify value, they will be provisioned inside default VPC.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Sachin's answer, you can, however, hit "copy to a security group" which is what i had to do. I made one which was a non-VPC security group, and thus I copied it after I made it to a VPC security group and that one showed up.